# What is `encode()` function detected in JaCoCo coverage report (for Kolin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jacoco

Recently I upgrade my gradle from 6.5.1 to 7.0 i.e.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip
```

After the upgrade, I notice my test coverage dropped.

After investigation, I found out that in Gradle 6.5.1, my JaCoCo test coverage report shows some of my class has an `encode()` function, but it no longer exists in Gradle 7.0.

I dig out the simplest example below. The code is as below

[image]

In Gradle 6.5, my JaCoCo report is as below (notice there's an additional `encode()` function.

[image]

However, in Gradle 7.0, my JaCoCo report is as below

[image]

Because of this missing covered function, hence my coverage dropped. Nonetheless, it looks like in Gradle 7.0, that is more correct, as my real code doesn't have `encode()`.

I'm just trying to understand where `encode()` function is there in the first place, and why it is no longer in Gradle 7.0? And is it correct that my assumption that Gradle 7.0 result is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different versions of Gradle come with different values of `jacoco.toolVersion` which you also [can change in your `build.gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:configuring_the_jacoco_plugin), and which controls version of JaCoCo to use.

[Gradle `6.5` by default uses JaCoCo `0.8.5`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension.html), and [starting from Gradle `6.7` default is `0.8.6`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension.html).

And here is a list of changes in JaCoCo version `0.8.6` - https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html

---

Most likely your interface `ContextData` contains method `encode` with default implementation.

JVM supports default methods in interfaces starting from version 8, however Kotlin supports compilation into bytecode of version 6. To do so Kotlin compiler does a trick  for such methods - it generates method in classes implementing this interface that merely delegates execution to default implementation:

for the following `Example.kt`

```
interface ContextData {
  fun encode() = { /* something */ }
}

data class SearchRefinementModalOpenData(
  val userAction: String?
) : ContextData
```

execution of

```
kotlin-compiler-1.4.32/bin/kotlinc Example.kt
javap -v -p SearchRefinementModalOpenData.class
```

shows following bytecode

```
public final class SearchRefinementModalOpenData implements ContextData
{
  public kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<kotlin.Unit> encode();
    descriptor: ()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokestatic  #29                 // Method ContextData$DefaultImpls.encode:(LContextData;)Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
         4: areturn
```

[JaCoCo starting from version `0.8.6` filters out such methods](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/1012) since they are compiler artifacts and not presented in original source code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using kotlinx.Serialization.

That generates a few encodeToString and similar functions for your objects. I guess Gradle 7 now ignores those?